# Contact form 7 - URL redirection

Tags: php, contact-form-7

As you guys know in CF7 `on_sent_ok` command deprecated and scheduled to be abolished by the end of 2017. So I decided to use the new script for redirecting my contact forms with this script provided by CF7

```
function add_this_script_footer(){ ?>

<script>
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
    location = 'http://websiteurl/thank-you';
}, false );
</script>

<?php } 

add_action('wp_footer', 'add_this_script_footer');
```

but this applies to all contact forms. Since I am using quite different types of forms, may I know how can I exclude one of them from this redirection?

Answer (score 0):

Try this script:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
    if (event.detail.contactFormId != '123') { // This would exclude form with id 123
        location = 'http://websiteurl/thank-you';
    }
}, false );
</script>
```

**Bonus tip:** I often do it another way that makes it a bit more flexible. I put a `<div class="do-some-action" data-something="foobar" style="display:none;"></div>` in the CF7 form itself and then I can put this action in multiple forms if needed..

```
<script>
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
    var $cf = $( '#' + event.detail.id );
    var $actionDiv = $cf.find( '.do-some-action' );
    if ( $actionDiv && $actionDiv.length ) {
        // Div with action class found
        // We can also extract some data if needed
        var something = $actionDiv.data( 'something' );
        console.log( 'something = ' + something );
        location = 'http://websiteurl/thank-you';
    }
}, false );
</script>
```

I hope this helps!